# Reviews do not show up in the admin panel

Tags: admin, review

On a catalog product page, users enter review in the form and click submit. Now I would expect the review to show up in the `Catalog -> Reviews` and `Ratings -> Customer Reviews -> Pending Reviews`.

It does not show up. What's wrong? Where do I need to look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is too broad one. But one quick check that you can perform would be Go to `System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced` and verify that `Mage_Review` model is in enabled state.

If that is not enabled state, then you should enable it.Otherwise that is the module that you should dig into in order to trace the issue.

### Edit-1

Ok then start digging. I will help you with the first step. Rest you should do. When submitting a new product review, this is what executing in Magento by default.

```
 ## app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
 Mage_Review_ProductController@postAction()
```

So do a test review and dig from here. Stop until find the problem.

**Note:** The above case only help, if you have problem with storing reviews in database. If reviews are storing perfectly, then you should look into the admin section. So do a test review and look into the tables whether entry is present there or not. Tables associated with `Mage_Review` module are *review, review_detail, review_status, review_entity, review_entity_summary, review_store*.

Comment: It's enabled, hmm interesting...

Comment: I found this https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dmgkmjeQzfYJ:dedalx.com/faq/product-reviews-does-not-submit-in-magento-1-8-x/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: had the same problem for a login page, users could not log in as the key was missing. hopefully it works for the reviews

Comment: okay.. like this dig more.. I did an edit. Hopefully it may help you.

Answer (score 3):

All done,

This is Magento 1.8 bug, but you can fix it:

Open file: `/app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/review/form.phtml`

Find:

```
<form action=”<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>” method=”post” id=”review-form”>
```

Add next:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```